# selenium IDE - how to storeText just the id within a link?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

How can I create a variable that has the id from one of my records on the index page?

I can use xpath to get at the anchor I want with:

```
storeText
//table[@id='districts']//tr/td/a[text()='Fairview Union']
id_of_another_district
```

but that gets the link name.  I want to id for that record, i.e. in the original source code I have:

```
<tr>
<td>
<a href="/districts/31">Fairview Union</a>
<span class='small'><a href="/users/change_district/31">(Select)</a></span>
</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td class='rightalign'>01/09/2012</td>
<td></td>
<td><a href="/districts/31/overview" class="report_link right"></a></td>
<td><a href="/districts/31" class="deleteicon" data-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete all data and schedules for Fairview Union?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow" title="Delete Fairview Union"><img alt="Delete" src="/assets/icons/delete-a77f3c3c125b0817085648f284c98938.png" /></a></td>
</tr>
```

and what I want to get and store in a variable in selenium is the record number 31

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the 'store' command, you can execute javascript code in the 'target' column...

`store  |  javascript{...}  | myVar`

where the `...` is, substitute it with the js you need to return the id.

[Edit from Michael]
I ended up using:

```
storeAttribute | //*[@class='small']/a[text()='(Select)']/@href        | hrefAttr
store          | javascript{storedVars['hrefAttr'].replace(/.*\//,'')} | myVar
echo           | ${myVar}
```

myVar now has the ID and I can do things like:

```
open
/users/change_district/${id_of_another_district}
```

Comment: What will the javascript be, given the page structure I've shown?

Comment: it's hard to tell, where is "id_to_another_district" coming from?  also - your <a>Fairview Union</a> doesn't even have an id

Comment: id_of_another_district is the variable I am trying to store the 31 in.  Fairview Union has /31/ instead of `?id=31` because it is a rails app.

Comment: ahhhh.. thank you, that clears up a bit.. i'll edit my response. thought you meant id as in the html attribute.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant i've been attempting to come up with a solution - and how about this one.  Why in your rails app, don't you just do `<%= link_to district.name, ..., :id=>district.id` so your html will output `<a id="31" href="..." />`

Comment: Yeah, if only i had 'the power' unfortunately I'm outside the code base, and not part of the programming group for this product.  Also I'll want to do a similar thing on three on other screens.  I do approeciate your help so far and if you work it out it's 25 points for you and you could probably also post it at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947258/javascript-how-to-store-the-id-of-a-link

Answer (score 0):

The answer of sircapsalot (edited by Michael Durrant) is ok, but it's a bit different in my environment, regarding how the javascript is executed: not with javascript{...} So, in my case it looks like this and it works fine:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeAttribute</td>
    <td>//html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/a@href</td>
    <td>hrefAttr</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>storedVars['hrefAttr'].replace(/.*=/,'')</td>
    <td>transportIdVar</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${transportIdVar}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

The href in my case looks like this:

```
http://example/local/IntegrationPick?partyId=8080595
```