# javascript - how to store the id of a link?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I'm trying to use the selenium IDE to get, store and use the id of a record.

The html is

```
<span class='small'><a href="/users/change_district/31">(Select)</a></span>
```

I want to get the `31` part of that and store it in variable myVar

The advice I am reading for selenium says to do it with javascript, i.e. have

```
store | javascript{...} | myVar
```

My question is: what should the `{...}` javascript code be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a combination of XPath and JavaScript to get that. Like this:

```
storeAttribute | //*[@class='small']/a[text()='(Select)']/@href        | hrefAttr
store          | javascript{storedVars['hrefAttr'].replace(/.*\//,'')} | myVar
echo           | ${myVar}
```

Output:

```
31
```

Comment: +1 Very cool yes this worked!  More info for others on this kinda stuff at http://www.questionselenium.com/2012/10/echo-storeeval-and-storedvars.html

Answer (score 0):

storeAttribute css=a[href*='users/change_district']@href HREF

assertEval javascript:{storedVars['HREF'] == '/users/change_district/31'} true

Please Let me know Is the above scripting is working or not.